# Loading a widget according to specific information on the piece-page

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have an issue regarding pages and widgets. In my `show.html` i have implemented a `{{apos.singleton(data.page, 'contact', 'contact', {})}}`.

The Contact should be specific to the `piece-page`.

I tried to give Informations through the options segment of the Singleton, but i have no access to the options, in my `contact-widget/index.js`

How can i get Information about my Page so i can load my Contact specifically for the Piece-Page im Looking at?

Comment: Clarifying question: what do you want to modify based on the options passed? The answer might impact where the options should be received

Comment: i wanna know, where the widget is implemented, so when i have a specific company on my page, i want to display a contact, that has a connection to that company. 

I solved this problem by getting my doc through the slug i have in my req.slug after i get my doc i match the company with the contacts and pick one that matches.

i just thought that there would be a simpler solution rather than loading the whole doc through the slug in my widget/index.js

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a widget in a specific context it would make sense to build in optional fields to the widget itself to tell it about its context. You could make them joins to other pieces of apostrophe content, or normal string/select/etc fields.

If the context is really more dynamic than that you could go through the widget's `load` method and sniff out `req` to see if you actually need to go fetch more data. More info on `load` here https://apostrophecms.org/docs/modules/apostrophe-widgets/index.html#load